# Prevent SQL injection in WebSQL database? (How to handle quotes in data?)

Tags: javascript, webkit, sql-injection, web-sql

I'm currently importing an xml export of a mysql database into a websql database for use in an online mobile experience.

Everything works fine and dandy until there are double quotes in whatever string I am inserting. Normally, in PHP I would be using something like: mysql_real_escape_string while inserting.

Options I know I can try is to write regex and make functions for adding/removing slashes. There are lots of examples on google for this - but what i'm looking to see is if anyone else has encountered this, and possibly has a better solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `string.replace("\"", "\\\"")` Will replace `"` by `\"`. It looks a bit odd but that's because the escape character needs to be escaped as well, funzies :P

Comment: that actually does work ... it converts spaces as well, but other then that seems like a solid solution. I guess I was over thinking this. haha.

Post as an answer and i'll mark it correct! ( the escape answer )

Comment: The primary issue is SQL injection; accidental or otherwise. I hope you find some good answers. The *best* solution is to *use placeholders*, if they are supported.

Comment: yeah sql injection --- and the xml that im importing has some HTML in it... causing it to error out once it reaches a quot =/

Answer (score 6):

Forget about escaping. Do the right thing: use placeholders. In this case data will never ever be treated as anything but raw data string. In Web SQL this can be done with [`executeSql`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#executing-sql-statements). See [pre-processing section](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#preprocess-the-sql-statement) on explanation on how this works.

Example straight from intro of document:

```
db.readTransaction(function (t) {
  t.executeSql('SELECT title, author FROM docs WHERE id=?', [id], function (t, data) {
    report(data.rows[0].title, data.rows[0].author);
  });
});
```

No matter what is in `id` variable, this request will look for verbatim value, never being interpreted as part of command.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution based on the spec. My solution is a hack.

Comment: Can it be done with INSERT INTO tablename (colnames) VALUES (?,?,?...) ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to use an AJAX request to send the XML string to PHP, which would return the string with quotes escaped.

Comment: Round-trip from client to arbitrary remote server on forming each query and equal server load multiplied by number of clients? Are you even serious?

Comment: The question didn't clarify the scenario, so we had different assumptions. I assumed going from localhost(127.0.0.1) to server-side once to untaint one large XML file. I've done such an operation successfully exporting from Wordpress.