# MySQL quotes, double quotes mess

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to insert content into a MySQL and it looks like that:

table name is `foo`
and the columns are:

```
     id INTEGER,
     name VARCHAR(50),
     content VARCHAR(255),
     url VARCHAR(255)
```

the problem arises when I'm trying to insert string which has quotes and double quotes inside it and escaping must be done since when inserting strings into MySQL you need to surround it in single quotes.

How do I escape the following text ?

```
'<div><a href='http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4391031,00.html'><img src='http://www.ynet.co.il/PicServer3/2013/06/11/4677612/AP0AMR108-Main-2013-05-25T16-54-20.070Z239775_a.jpg' alt='צילום: AP' title='צילום: AP' border='0' width='116' height='116'></a></div>בית המשפט העליון אישר בהחלטה תקדימית לחיילים ושוטרים להצביע בבחירות - לראשונה מאז שנות ה-70. האיסלאמיסטים זעמו על הפסיקה בעוד הליברלים ואנשי האופוזיציה בירכו: "יש מדינות שמעניקות לאנשי הצבא שלהן להצביע בבחירות ובהם דרום אפריקה, ברזיל, הודו, רוסיה, ארצות הברית, ואפילו ישראל"'
```

Comment: Have you tried as string like this: `"some content \"yes!\""` ?

Comment: You didn't tag any programming language, but if you would use prepared statements, there is no need for escaping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent SQL injection in WebSQL database? (How to handle quotes in data?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148599/prevent-sql-injection-in-websql-database-how-to-handle-quotes-in-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape quotes with backslash:

```
insert into foo (id,name,content,url) values (0, 'test123', '<div id=\'test\'>ת"\א היא עיר מצוינת</div>', 'http://www.cnn.com')
```

You can also use the opposite kind of quotes:

```
insert into foo (id,name,content,url) values (0, 'test123', "someContent's", 'http://www.cnn.com')
```

Here's how to do it with WebSQL parameterized queries:

```
transaction.executeSQL('INSERT INTO foo (id, name, content, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
    [0, 'test123', '<div id=\'test\'>ת"\א היא עיר מצוינת</div>', 'http://www.cnn.com'],
    callbackfn);
```

Comment: That won't solve my issue since 'someContent' can be <div id='test'>ת"א היא עיר מצוינת</div>

Comment: Escape all the quotes with backslash, what's the problem?

Comment: thx for your answer. I've updated the string that raises me the problem. Can you assist me on that please ?

Comment: The answer is the same: put a backslash before every quote.

Comment: Are you doing this from a programming language like PHP? If so, you should use parametrized queries, they will take care of this automatically.

Comment: var content = content.replace(/"/g,'\\"').replace(/'/g,"\\'")

Comment: How are you doing queries using Javascript? Web SQL?

Comment: I can't use parametrized queries since I'm using WebSQL (sqllite) and it doesnt support it

Comment: According to the question I just linked to above, WebSQL does support parametrized queries.

Comment: thx, I will try it tomorrow and will let you know.. thx alot!

Answer (score 0):

You escape any string only for what's around it. So if you want to put double quotes around this one, you have to protect only the double quote inside.

Comment: I'm getting the content from somewhere I can't control if inside it will have quotes or double quotes, it can have both

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a quote using `\` also known as the escape character. Have a look at [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html) that showcases the available escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
insert into foo (id,name,content,url) values (0,'test123','someContent\'s','http:\/\/www.cnn.com')
```