# Unicode character (\u0022) is showing backslash with double prime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Trying to handle this string `8202D-Ti-36&quot;` (This is &quote; HTML entity for inch/double quote) to #`8202D-Ti-36"` using replace function in C#  `Replace("&quot;", "\u0022")`, the replacement is working fine but replaced string is displaying with `8202D-Ti-36\"` backslash.

Expected result is : `8202D-Ti-36"`

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is how the debugger *displays* double quotes within a string. If you wite the string to a file or the console, you will see that it is as you expect it to be.

Comment: The debugger (display) will show values of type string in double quotes - so that you know it is a string. Then, when that string _contains_ a quote, it will be escaped (with a backslash) just you would do in actual code when specifying such a value. IOW, if "printed" or otherwise output, the `\"` you see will indeed just be a `"`.

Comment: Thank you guys. @Christian.K 
Please see the print screen, this is how data is saving in DB. 
https://prnt.sc/mykGT76lRPjH

Answer (score 0):

It just worked as expected,  `\"` is an embedded quotation mark,you could check this doc related : [how to put quotation marks in a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-put-quotation-marks-in-a-string-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Thank you guys. Please see the print screen, this is how data is saving in DB. prnt.sc/mykGT76lRPjH

Comment: Hi,@ Kaif Hasan, a  similar case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698040/how-to-add-a-string-containg-a-double-quote-to-a-sql-database  ,hopes help